# Mage registry key already exist error "_singleton/plumbase/feed"

Tags: magento1.9.3

> >
>   https://www.activaboualaa.com/errors/report.php?id=414409631915&skin=default
>
> > >

There has been an error processing your request
Mage registry key "_singleton/plumbase/feed" already exists

Trace:

```
#0 /home/activ/public_html/app/Mage.php(225): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /home/activ/public_html/app/Mage.php(479): Mage::register('_singleton/plum...', false)
#2 /home/activ/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(22325): Mage::getSingleton('plumbase/feed')
#3 /home/activ/public_html/app/Mage.php(450): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#4 /home/activ/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(14225): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#5 /home/activ/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action.php(167): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#6 /home/activ/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(14116): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#7 /home/activ/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(18849): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login')
#8 /home/activ/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(18379): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#9 /home/activ/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(21354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#10 /home/activ/public_html/app/Mage.php(686): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 /home/activ/public_html/index.php(82): Mage::run('', 'store')
#12 {main}
```

Comment: remove var/cache/*

Answer (score 1):

first unregister key

```
Mage::unregister($your_key)
```

after that set data

```
Mage::register($your_key, $your_data)
```

and get data

```
Mage::registry($your_key)
```